# Laptop BSoD when unplugged

Tags: windows-10, bsod

My laptop runs on windows 10.
Until today, the laptop froze for a couple of seconds every 5 seconds unless plugged in.
But now, when i unplug it, i get what i got before.
A freeze after 5 seconds, but instead of the freeze ending, i got a BSoD.

Any way to fix this?

Also, one more thing.

When its plugged in, the laptop can easily run most games that require good hardware.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Battery's probably dead. Can't say much more with so little information.

Comment: Nah, its a BSoD, when i reboot it, it works, then 5 mins later a BSoD if i dont plug it back in.